# PHP - Remove all characters from string except listed characters and line returns

Tags: php, regex

I have a php input filter that cleans all unwanted characters from a string.
This:

```
$clean = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9 \.\-\"_',]/i", "", $string);
```

This works fine, but I also what to preserve all character returns in the string.
I've tried different things like adding '\n\r' or '\R' or '\n\r' to the list of characters in the brackets or adding '/m' to the flag.
I'm just not finding the right combo.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you use `"/[^a-z0-9 .\-\"_',\r\n]/i"`? Or ``"/[^a-z0-9.\"_',\s-]/i"``?

Comment: These suggestions also still strip line returns. When I output the strings to a log file I get:
before:
"line 1\r\nline 2"

after filter:
"line 1line 2"

Comment: Wiktor, you had it right "/[^a-z0-9 .\-\"_',\r\n]/i" works!
My code was filtering elsewhere and I attributed it to this filter.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: Hi Scotty, you removed the accерt mark from my answer, is there an issue still? Could you clarify what does not work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```php
$clean = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9 .\"_',\r\n-]/i", "", $string);
```

Note

- The added `\r\n`
- The dot does not have to be escaped inside a character class
- The `-` char  is put to the end of the character class and it does not have to be escaped there.

Comment: This looks like the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a character class to match any non-printable characters:

```php
$clean = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9 \.\-\"_',\p{C}]/i", "", $string);
```